# How to get node integration working in an Electron Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, electron, web-worker

I [read the docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/multithreading), and I have enabled node integration:

```
win = new Electron.BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
        // allow code inside this window to use use native window.open()
        nativeWindowOpen: true,
        nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
    },
})
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. I get errors in the worker like

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

on lines like

```
var _ = require("lodash")
```

How do we make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Using `require` inside a worker works.

I made a bare minimal example here: https://github.com/trusktr/electron-web-worker-example.

There must be something wrong in my actual project (which is huge compared to that example, and is doing some custom TypeScript transpilation).

EDIT, the problem in my case was this (see solution there): https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15609